# Map a single object using Stream

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is this a good use case of java 8's Stream:

```
final Car carWithInterior = Stream.of(carWithEngine)
            .map(car -> installSeats.execute(car))
            .map(car -> installDashBoard.execute(car))
            .map(car -> installSunRoof.execute(car))
            .collect(car);
```

`carWithEngine` is a `Car`. Note that sometimes even if the car (w/ dashboard) is pass to the installSunroof, it will not do any since there's no hole in the roof. I should **always get a car at the end** of the installation/mapping process.

The **installation sequence is required** (that's why I thought of streaming it) and next installation may sometimes need a parameter from the pass car instance to perform it's operation.

1. Is this a good use case for java 8's Stream?
2. Obvioulsy, my collect at the end is not right. How should I get the car at the end of this installation/assembly line? `findFirst().get()` will work but I think that's bad, since I should always get a car at the end even if the installation didn't do anything with the `carWitEngine` and I'm not stream multiple elements.

*I'm not sure how cars are assembled but let say you need to put the engine first before adding the interiors for the sake of this analogy*

Comment: Looks more like a case for a builder pattern

Comment: You may use method reference instead of lambdas here. `.map(installSeats::execute)` and so on. Less clutter, easier to read.

Comment: @Zabuza, thanks, yup I will do that. But will keep it this way in case some don't understand method ref

Comment: If you are dealing with a series of cars (or parts to assemble into a car), then yea stream is definitely the way to go

Comment: What kind of collector is `car`?

Comment: If you're trying to avoid nested method calls like `installSunRoof.execute(installDashBoard.execute(installSeats.execute(car)))`, you could just use assignments like `car = installSeats.execute(car); car = installDashBoard.execute(car); car = installSunRoof.execute(car);`. That formats the same way as the code with the stream or optional, but it doesn't do any pointless operations.

Comment: @shmosel, like I said in #2, my collect at the end is not right. Haven't explored yet how to collect it

Comment: There is alot of potential code smells from the way you posed your question. What does your installSunroof.execute return? and can it return null? It's possible that you are not approaching the problem at hand correctly.

Comment: @shinjw A car, evidently.

Comment: @shmosel i meant... can it return null?

Comment: @Radiodef so far, I'm with you. Thanks!

Comment: @Radiodef. This would be all the more reason to be using a builder pattern. Phil's comment should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're looking to perform operations on a single object. Java 8 [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) would be appropriate.

The **builder pattern** (Phil C's comment) is definitely worth visiting if each of these map operations are simply hydrating the `Car` object.

1. Tapping open a stream for a single object is not a good use case for streams.
2. You're venturing into dangerous territory (side-effecty) if the `Car` gets dropped in the stream through a `.map()` operation. When dealing with `Streams` it is highly recommended to use these operations the way they are intended. If you plan on dropping an element from a stream `.filter()`

Edit to OP's edits:

There is some fundamental confusion around "sequence" and how that that translates

**Optional**

```
 car => map(execute) => map(execute) => transformedcar
```

**Streams**

```
[car1, car2, car3]
     => map(execute) => map(execute) => updatedcar1                |  => findFirst (Optional<Car>)
           => map(execute) => map(execute) =>  updatedcar2         |
                 => map(execute) => map(execute) => updatedcar3    |
                                                                collect
                                                 [updatedcar1, updatedcar2, updatedcar3]
```

The `findFirst` method will return an `Optional`.
The `collect` method will provide a terminal operation that lets you aggregate/reduce/group these results.

These `map` operations transform the passed elements "sequentially". But a `Stream` would be appropriate cases where you must deal with many or "sequence of" cars.

*To revisit #2*

You have the option of providing an alternative with Optional with `orElse(car)`.

But this is where you have to be contentious of the side effects you are performing.

If the execute method is manipulating and returning the same object that was passed into it, there will be unintended consequences. I'll be using Optionals for example but same will apply for Streams.

```
private final Car car Optional.of(carWithEngine)
   .map(installSunroof.execute)   // <-- updatedCarWithSunroof
   .map(installDashboard.execute) // <-- updatedCarWithSunroofAndDashboard
   .orElse(carWithEngine)         // <-- updatedCarWithSunroofAndDashboard
```

Answer (score 6):

Answering your questions:

> 1. Is this a good use case for java 8's Stream?

No, the Java Stream Api is meant to be use on collections. From [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) the definition of a stream is:

> a sequence of elements from a source that supports aggregate
>   operations

You have a single object that is not a sequence of elements, so the use of Stream make your code more difficult to understand. To answer question 2, you can do

```
findFirst().orElse(carWithEngine)
```

An alternative to your example is simply to nest the function calls, like this:

```
installSunRoof.execute(installDashBoard.execute(installSeats.execute(car)))
```

Another alternative will be to define a method install on the car that receives a BaseIinstaller and returns the modified car, something like this:

```
final Car carWithInterior = car.install(installSeats)
                               .install(installDashBoard)
                               .install(installSunRoof);
```